# Stick a window to the side of the screen so that it actually splits the screen (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7

I just removed Windows 7 Home Premium and installed Windows 7 Ultimate instead. However, the feature that I had used from the beginning was the ability to actually stick a window to the side of the screen, so that it literally divided the screen.

What I mean is that, when I e.g. put my IM client to the right side of the screen and then open Notepad and maximize it, it will only fill up the space my IM client didn't reserve.

*I am 99% sure* I did not have any additional software installed for this feature. However, I can't find a way to do it now.

Comment: To my knowledge no such feature is built in. The IM app probably used a [Windows API Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177).

Comment: @digitxp; yeah, many IM clients I've seen do do this.

Comment: Why not stick something to the left? Windows'  built-in feature allows something stick to the right and left at the same time.

Comment: The windows feature @SgtOJ is referring to is called Aero Snap (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/snap), but the behaviour isn't exactly what you're describing, so I'd probably go with what digitxp suggested.

Comment: The only built-in way to get a similar effect is to use Windows Key + right arrow with your IM client, and Windows Key + left arrow with Notepad. The IM client will be snapped to the right, and Notepad will fill the left of the screen (but will not be truly maximised).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a tiling windows manager.

I don't know of one that will do it automatically though.  There are several AutoHotkey scripts out there that can be modified to provide this functionality though.