# Is there a way to dock an app on the side of screen so other apps maximize to the side of it?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, desktop, window-manager, aero-snap

I've seen a few apps (such as instant messaging apps) that will dock to the side of the screen and essentially shrink your total desktop space, meaning that any apps that are maximized on that monitor will only take up the space to the side of the app and aero snap will snap to the side of the app as well.

I'm trying to mimic this behavior with a website in chrome run as a desktop app (Chrome settings > More tools > Add to desktop...).

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/330407/stick-a-window-to-the-side-of-the-screen-so-that-it-actually-splits-the-screen) that addresses the issue for Windows 7 without much in the way of an answer, but I was wondering if there was anything new with Windows 10 and its improved aero snap features that addresses this issue.

Is there a solution within windows 10, a 3rd party tiling app, or an autohotkey script to accomplish this?

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? http://www.donationcoder.com/software/mouser/other-windows-apps/desktopcoral

Comment: @wysiwyg Yes! This is awesome! Only thing it's missing is 1.) the ability to link it to a specific app to fill or be in the dock (I have to create the dock and then manually size the app in the dock area where I want it - I can't aero snap it or anything) and 2.) the ability to make the app always on top. To get around these, I can just manually size and place my app at the beginning of each work day and use an autohotkey script to keep it on top. Not absolutely perfect as it requires a little setup, but it works! Thanks so much!